# grpc over tls: multiple server certificates

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc

The grpc server side api assumes multiple server side certificates (see pem_key_cert_pairs), all examples use only one. What is the practical need for multiple certificates on the server side?

Comment: Server might supports multiple cryptoalgorithms (e.g. couple RSAs and couple ECDSAs) and want to support legacy clients which don't support the strongest one of them. To verify, check details of these certificates.

Comment: @Soonts It seems like an answer, thank you.